# Error checking if Bluetooth is enabled in Android (REQUEST_ENABLE_BT cannot be resolved to a variable)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to do this:

```
    BluetoothAdapter bt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bt == null){
        //Does not support Bluetooth
        status.setText("Your device does not support Bluetooth");
    }else{
        //Magic starts. Let's check if it's enabled
        if (!bt.isEnabled()){
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }   
    }
```

But I get this error:

> REQUEST_ENABLE_BT cannot be resolved to a variable

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`REQUEST_ENABLE_BT` is a request code that you provide.  It's really just a number that you provide for `onActivityResult`.  It will be the `requestCode` (first parameter) of `onActivityResult` when the activity returns.  You could put any number you want as long as it's consistent in the return method.

In other words, put a line like this in the top of your Activity:

`private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;`

Answer (score 7):

The [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) says
The REQUEST_ENABLE_BT constant passed to startActivityForResult() is a locally defined integer (which must be greater than 0), that the system passes back to you in your onActivityResult() implementation as the requestCode parameter.

You can pass any integer value > 0 there.

Answer (score -9):

override method startActivityForResult as bellow.

```
private void startActivityForResult(Intent enableBtIntent,Object rEQUEST_ENABLE_BT2) {
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this answer doesn't have a -100 because it's incorrect from the beginning to the end. 1) You cannot override a method with a different signature (except for covariant subtypes). 2) You cannot override a method and reducing its access level. 3) You didn't give any hint what should be in this new method and why it's needed. 4) Adding a different method does not help answering what the parameter to the existing method should be used for. 5) changing the name of a parameter doesn't affect its function 6) your ALL_CAPS mixed with camelCase is very strange. Phew.