# Can't use Android BT API methods

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app that needs a BT connection. After reading the Android Developers page, the given method such us `isEnabled()` doesn't work. The error is `cannot resolve symbol isEnabled`.
The imported library is `android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter`. In the manifest file, following the instructions of the Android page, I also have inserted the permission to Bluetooth, BT admin and fine location.
The code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
    Log.i("Fallo","Dispositivo sin bluetooth");
}

if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    Intent enableBtIntent = new     Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating your BluetoothAdapter object outside the onCreate method. Put everything inside the onCreate curly brackets.

Comment: still one error in `startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT` show same error in `REQUEST_ENABLE_BT`

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188277/error-checking-if-bluetooth-is-enabled-in-android-request-enable-bt-cannot-be-r

This is not related with the initial question,though.